# Why can't I put more than one control on a window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Problem:

[image: Problem in Visual Studio designer]

XAML file:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test" Height="398.775" Width="782" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0" IsTabStop="True">
    <Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
        <TaskbarItemInfo/>
    </Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="268,290,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: You need to add a container that is capable of holding multiple children and add your controls to that.

Comment: The Content of a Window can only be a single UI element. In order to add multiple child elements, use a Panel as top level element, typically a Grid or DockPanel. When you create a new WPF project, there should by default be a Grid.

Comment: Welcome!  Consider adding a description of your problem into your question's body.  This helps today and future readers as well as search engines.  Not all browsers support animations or the user might have them disabled

Answer (score 6):

A [`Window`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window?view=netcore-3.1) is a [`ContentControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol?view=netcore-3.1). These have a [`Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content?view=netcore-3.1) property to display a single item. If you want to display multiple items, use one of the following built-in [layout panels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview) and drag them onto your window. Then you can add multiple controls to them.

- [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=netcore-3.1)
- [StackPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.stackpanel?view=netcore-3.1)
- [WrapPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.wrappanel?view=netcore-3.1)
- [DockPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel?view=netcore-3.1)
- [UniformGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)
- [Canvas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're on the window who only accepts 1 element, you need first add a content controller .

It can be:

- Grid
- Canvas
- Dock Panel
- StackPanel
- WrapPannel
- Scroll viewer

Answer (score -1):

Add `<grid> </grid>` in Window tag then you can add your controls in it.